# How to do this initialization?

Tags: c, struct, initialization, c-preprocessor

I have a structure, which I need to initialize at compile time. Here is the current (pseudo)code:

```
struct A
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct B
{
    struct A а[16][3];
};

#define DEFAULT {{ \
                   .a = 1, \
                   .b = 2, \
                 }, \ 
                 { \
                   .a = 3, \
                   .b = 8, \
                 }, \
                 { \
                   .a = 11, \
                   .b = 29, \
                }}

#define DEFAULT2 DEFAULT, DEFAULT
#define DEFAULT4 DEFAULT2, DEFAULT2
#define DEFAULT8 DEFAULT4, DEFAULT4
#define DEFAULT16 DEFAULT8, DEFAULT8

struct B b = {{DEFAULT16}};
```

I don't understand this code:

- Why do we need double braces on the last line?
- Moreover, why do we need the double braces in the definition of DEFAULT. I understand that

  ```
               {
                 .a = 3,
                 .b = 8,
               }
  ```

is an ordinary structure initialization. But the second pair of braces seems as if I am initializing `b` as an array of `16` objects of type `struct A [3]`. Why not simply list the values of `b` as if it were a 1-dimensional array (the same way that one can access `b[20]`)?

- Thirdly, now I need to add a new field to `struct B` and have no idea how to modify the initialization. The new `struct B` shall be:

  ```
               struct B
               {
                  int c[16];
                  struct A a[16][3];
               }
  ```

Compiler is arm-none-eabi-gcc 4.7.2 with no flags to enforce any **C** standard.

Comment: Compile your code with `gcc -E` to get the output after the preprocessor has done his job. I guess the output will help you understanding what the macro does.

Comment: @user2799037, thanks, this is usually the correct approach. However, this time the pre-processed code is just as I anticipated it to be. And I still don't know how does it work.

Comment: Paranthesis for inside array elements are not mandatory. So you can initialize your `struct B`  as *1 dimensional array*.

Comment: @MadHatter, deleting the first and last `{` for `DEFAULT` reuslts in `error: field name not in record or union initializer`.

Comment: On the other hand, removing one of the braces in `b = ` results in `error: field name not in record or union initializer`. The pre-processed with `-E` code has 4 leading braces: `{{{{ .a = 1, ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly,

One brace is needed for things within `struct A`, e.g.

```
struct A a = { .a = 1, .b = 2 };
```

Two braces are needed for a two dimensional array, e.g.

```
int array[2][2] = {
  { 1, 1 },
  { 1, 1 }
};
```

The final brace is needed for things within `struct B`.

Finally, to add `int c[16]` to `struct B`, you can replace the last line of your snippet with the following:

```
struct B b = {{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{DEFAULT16}};
```

Or use proper macro substitution for readability.

Comment: Edited ';'-s in. Solved my problem by `#define LQLQ {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1} {LQLQ, {DEFAULT16}};`. Now that I do not have the direct problem, it is difficult to judge if I fully understand the syntax. Accepting your answer as helpful. Thank you!